# Where are the address ranges in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, address

I recall coming across some OSM initiative that was proposing to put US address ranges in the data using TIGER (I think). However, I have seen no such ranges in any of the data I have looked at so far.

I am wondering if anyone has noticed this kind of information or can point me in the direction of concrete descriptions of its existence (or lack thereof). If it does not exist, is there a method for extracting address ranges from what is given in nodes and ways?

I know the data can be very spotty, but assuming a perfect world of open source data editing, if a way is comprised of nodes that each have an address, could one extrapolate To-From address ranges for the left and right side of the line?

Answer (score 6):

There is this site **Openaddresses.io**

https://openaddresses.io/

[image]
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TIGER_to_OSM_Attribute_Map#Address_Ranges

Comment: This is interesting. I wonder what the downloadable data will look like. This doesn't really address the problem of obtaining ranges for use, though.

Comment: This link is out of date

Comment: @AvidDabbler https://openaddresses.io/ updated link *(was 10 years ago)

Comment: Figured as much. Just wasn't sure if it was a dead project. Looks great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not all roads have street ranges on them, but there is a fair amount of support for address points depending on where you are looking and can see them on the standard OSM layer. You can inspect address points by going to the layers panel and clicking "Map Data" and then clicking on the point.